# Symfony sessions and phpunit trouble

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have code in my controller like this:

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $verifiedResponse

 * @Route(...)

 * @return mixed
 */
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $session->set('key', mt_rand(0, 999));

    if ($request->get('key') === $session->get('key')) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return $session->get('key');
    }
    throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
}
```

And here is my 2 unit tests:

```
public function testSomeActionFirst()
{
   $client = static::createClient();
   $client->request('POST', $this->generateRoute('my_route'));
   return $client->getResponse()->getContent();
}

public function testSomeActionSecond($key)
{
   $client = static::createClient();
   $client->request('POST', $this->generateRoute('my_route'), [], [
       'key' => $key
   ]);
   $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isOk()
}
```

And second test always fails, because response code is `403`, because sessions does not saving between requests. How I can fix it?

Comment: you should make two consecutive call inside the same test method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each test method is suppose to be run in **isolation**. Otherwise you'd run into hard to **debug issues** as one test would be influencing others. Single test failure would lead to failures of other tests. Such a test suite will give you very little value, as failing tests won't tell you what went wrong.
You might not recognise this is a problem at first, but **maintaining** such a test suite quickly becomes very hard.

Therefore you should be able to **run each test separately**.

You should also be able to **run tests in any order**.

The web client you're using in your tests already follows these rules and is being reset before each test method is run. Although it's technically possible to [introduce test dependencies](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies), even with such an approach the client would be reset. It's a good thing!

If you need to perform some common actions in each test case, create helper methods that will encapsulate (and name!) that behaviour. For example:

```php
class MyTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $client;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient();
    }

    public function testSomeActionSecond()
    {
       $key = $this->requestKey();

       $this->client->request(
           'POST',
           $this->generateRoute('my_route'), 
           [],
           ['key' => $key]
       );

       $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk()
    }

    private function requestKey()
    {
       $this->client->request('POST', $this->generateRoute('my_route'));

       return $this->client->getResponse()->getContent();
    }
}
```